# Why rotation and reflection do not form groups under composition of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning about groups in abstract algebra. I am trying to understand why the set of all rotations of the plane does not form a group under composition of
functions. Secondly why the set of all reflections of the plane does not form a group under composition of functions. I would appreciate if someone could elaborate on these.

I understand that it has something to do with one of the properties of groups not being true for the given circumstance, however I proved in a previous exercise that all rotations of $C$ around a fixed point form a group under composition of functions. So this is actually confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then that's it -- the fact that rotations may not rotate *around the same point* must somehow screw things up.

Comment: @pjs36 I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm saying that you proved rotations *do* form a group - provided they rotate around the same, fixed point. But when you consider *all* rotations, they don't necessarily rotate around the same point, which must be what prevents what you'd just proven from applying.

Comment: @pjs36 Is it that since we are rotating/reflecting an entire plane as opposed to a single point, then each point on the plane has to be translated to the origin and back? So this some how does not form a group?

Comment: @pjs36 Ok, I see. That would make sense. The question is how to show that this is true in a proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Compute the composition of the rotation by $\pi$ around the origin and the rotation by $\pi$ around a fixed point (which is not the origin). You can even consider the line instead of the plane.

Comment: I took an arbitrary point (a,b). I found that rotation about the origin yields $e^{i \pi} z$ and about the point $(a,b)$ yields $e^{i \pi} (z-a-bi) + a + bi$. How would I interpret this result?

Comment: @Nid: Is this a rotation or reflection?

Comment: By the way, $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: This was a rotation.

Comment: @Nid: You did not calculate the *composition*.

Comment: Around the angle $\pi$ you suggested.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. But the composition just yields $z$.

Comment: @Nid: I meant for you to compose two *different* rotations. If you rotate by $\pi$ and then rotate by $\pi$ again around the same point, of course you'll get identity.

Comment: I thought you meant pick two different points and rotate them by  $\pi$. I chose $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The set is not closed under composition.

For example, the reflection through $x=1$ followed by the reflection through $x=2$ results in a translation of 2 along the x-axis, and this is neither a rotation nor a reflection.

Translations, reflections and rotations together *do* form a group, however.

A similar thing can be said for just translations with rotations (no reflections). Given a point P and two rotations $r_1,r_2$, you can find a translation $t$ such that $tr_2r_1(P)=P$, and this means that the composition is an orientation preserving isometry with a fixed point, aka a rotation. Thus $tr_2r_1=r_3$ and $r_2r_1=t^{-1}r_3$. This shows the composition of two rotations is in the group generated by rotations and translations.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if I choose two different points of reflection,  then this violates the closure property of groups because the composition of the two is a translation.

Similarly, If I take two different points of rotation, the composition is not a rotation but rather a translation. So this would also violate closure. Meaning this also is not a group under composition.

Comment: There is not a *point* of reflection, there is a *line* of reflection. Reflections through distinct parallel lines compose to a translation. If the lines cross at a point, they compose to a rotation around the point.

Comment: I under stand that. My other question is why can't reflection across two different lines like you said, be represented as a reflection across a single line say in between x=1 and x=2?

Comment: @Nid A reflection reverses the orientation of the plane, and two reflections in succession would preserve orientation. You can't both flip and not flip the plane at the same time

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I forgot that we are flipping the entire plane through a line rather than just individual points.

Answer (score 0):

If the reflection is along a line passing through the center of rotation, it will form a group. But we will need to do some trickery, for example translate the "point of operation" to origo before applying the operation and then of course translate back after completed operation. Say the center of operation is $\bf p_0$.

$$ {\bf v} = \left[\begin{array}{l}\bf p\\ \bf p_0\end{array}\right], {\bf S}^{-1} = \bf \left[\begin{array}{rr}I& \bf-I\\\bf 0 &\bf I\end{array}\right], {\bf S} = \bf \left[\begin{array}{rr}I& \bf I\\\bf 0 &\bf I\end{array}\right]$$
Where S defines a similarity to the operation $\bf G_k$ incapsulated like this. ( It is this $\bf G_k$ which is rotation / reflection matrix ).
$$\left[\begin{array}{ll}\bf G_k& \bf 0\\\bf 0 &\bf I\end{array}\right]$$

---

We could also achieve the same thing by instead choosing our similarity to be defined by $${\bf S} = \bf \left[\begin{array}{rr}I& \bf -I\\\bf 0 &\bf -I\end{array}\right]$$

If we accept that $\bf p_0$ will be reflected in origo meanwhile inside the similarity transformation. This can be convenient because in this case $\bf S = S^{-1}$.

---

Conceptually in this case maybe it will be better to bake $\bf p_0$ into the matrices. This can be done by moving $\bf p_0$ into the matrix and lifting out the ones in the diagonal like this: $${\bf v} =  \left[\begin{array}{l}\bf p\\ \text{diag}({\bf I})\end{array}\right],  \bf S = \bf \left[\begin{array}{ll}I& \text{diag}({\bf p_0})\\\bf 0 & \bf I\end{array}\right]$$

In this way the center of operation $\bf p_0$ becomes part of the transformation and not part of the data, as is more convenient as we are talking about matrix representations of groups and the multiplication with $\bf v$ actually is a group action from a group element on the set of points in space.